# Shade auto smooth not working, turning objects black

Tags: shaders, smooth

[image]

I'm a beginner and I'm trying the Polygon runway tutorial with a cafe.

After I finished the modeling when I clicked to auto shade smooth at angle 180 some objects turned black.
Also if I change the value the objects just remain the same.

Any ideas how to shade it correctly?

here is the file:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: When you set it to an _Angle_ of 180° all edge angles **below** this value are considered smooth (unless you mark them as sharp) - which means, there are no edges recognized as sharp. Set the value to something reasonable in the 30° to 60° range (usually the default value of 30° works quite well).

Comment: @taiyo I added the file

Comment: Hi, Alesia, I was going to answer, but others have got there first with the major points. Here's [a tweaked version of your file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1zVKw06P/) you might want to compare with your own. (Not claiming perfection, just improvement)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems with your model. First the lamp, enable *Face Orientation* and you will see that the lamp's outside is flipped to the inside (you can also see trouble on the ground mesh, coming later to that):

[image]

Select the lamp, go to face edit mode, select all faces and do *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*:

[image]

Next the little boxes on the roof. Select one, go to vertex edit mode, select all vertices and do right click and *Merge Vertices > By Distance*. This should merge 4 vertices and fix the shading immediately because the *Bevel* modifier on that object now can work correctly again. Fix the other roof boxes the same way.

[image]

Now the ground, you have some messed up geometry there. Select object `Plane`, go to face edit mode and select the top face. Switch to vertex edit mode and hit the `Del` key and select *Vertices*. The red colored faces should disappear. `Plane` has still open parts, but they are hidden by other geometry and it fits, that may be ok for you.

[image]

Finally, if you inspect the ground further there is a plane `Plane.001` which seems unneeded. Also notice the shading of `Plane.002` which looks dubious (green arrows). Again there are overlapping vertices. Remove them as shown before and the shading works again.

[image]

Side note: Like @GordonBrinkmann points out, you  should potentionally use lower values for smooth shading. Your shading works only that way because you have a *Bevel* modifier applied everywhere.

Comment: thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out your lamp is inside-out, among other things. This is just a supplementary note.

You might consider a tip I picked up from [John Dickinson](https://www.youtube.com/@Motionworks)'s videos a while back. In User Preferences > Themes > 3D View,  set the display of Face Orientation: Front to completely transparent, and Face Orientation: Back to an eye-friendly tint. That means you can leave the Face Orientation overlay switched on all the time while modelling. and see immediately which way your normals are pointing.

[image]

Another suggestion might be to add this setting to display wireframe to your Quick menu:

[image]

.. which means you can quickly check the effect of modifiers (in particular, *Bevel* ) on your topology, in Object Mode.